# How to change colors nth number of times in django template using css?

Tags: css, sass

I want to add new colors to the tags everytime i add a new tag...Now i am using

> {{forloop.counter}}

But i want to use sass nth selectors so that i can add colors up to nth time with the colors available. Like github or gitlab tags

```
 {% for tag in tags %}
 <span class="text-left color{{forloop.counter}}tag_class_acc"id="list_tag"
 data-link="{{tag.id}}" style="cursor: pointer;">{{ tag.name }}</span>
 {% endfor %}
```

I got one article but i did not understand how to implement it.

[nth generator](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/azbwJm)

Comment: How are you capturing/storing your tags? Could you paste a sample file section.

Comment: Select the tag itself and use the pseudoselector nth like: `.tag_class_acc:nth-child(n){...}`

Comment: @bbh i did not understand whats the use of storing tags here...I want to show colors for each tags nth number of times if i will add more tags. I dont want to use forloop here

Comment: @llobet its not working

Comment: @bbh did you changed the 'n' for a number?

Comment: @Dev Can you post a screenshot or visual representation, overall, this question needs more details, ...